# Regex to match single dots but not numbers or reticences

Tags: python, regex

I'm working on a sentencizer and tokenizer for a tutorial. This means splitting a document string into sentences and sentences into words. Examples:

```
#Sentencizing
"This is a sentence. This is another sentence! A third..."=>["This is a sentence.", "This is another sentence!", "A third..."]
#Tokenizatiion
"Tokens are 'individual' bits of a sentence."=>["Tokens", "are", "'individual'", "bits", "of", "a", "sentence", "."]
```

As seen, there's a need for something more than just a string.split(). I'm using re.sub() appending a 'special' tag for each match (and later splitting in this tag), first for sentences and then for tokens.

So far it works great, but there's a problem: **how to make a regex that can split at dots, but not at (...) or at numbers (3.14)?**

I've been working with these options with lookahead (I need to match the group and then be able to recall it for appending), but none works:

```
#Do a negative look behind for preceding numbers or dots, central capture group is a dot, do the same as first for a look ahead.
(?![\d\.])(\.)(?<![\d\.])
```

The application is:

```
sentence = re.sub(pattern, '\g<0>'+special_tag, raw_sentence)
```

Comment: You have your lookarounds the wrong way round, it should be lookbehind-pattern-lookahead i.e. `(?<![\d\.])(\.)(?![\d\.])`

Comment: It would get easier if you first replace `...` with the [ellipsis](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm) character.

Comment: Thanks @Nick! Silly me. It works, but just as a patch, I have to remove preceding digits from exclusion so that "The year is 1984." Is caught.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following to find the periods that it looked like were relevant:

```
import re
m = re.compile(r'[0-9]\.[^0-9.]|[^0-9]\.[^0-9.]|[!?]')
st = "This is a sentence. This is another sentence! A third...  Pi is 3.14.  This is 1984.  Hello?"
m.findall(st)

# if you want to use lookahead, you can use something like this:
m = re.compile(r'(?<=[0-9])\.(?=[^0-9.])|(?<=[^0-9])\.(?=[^0-9.])|[!?]')
```

It's not particularly elegant, but I also tried to deal with the case of "We have a .1% chance of success."

Good luck!

Comment: To really make it function I had to use lookahead and lookbehind, such as in Nick's comment in the question, but this gave me the direction. I'm now using this: '(?<![\d\.])(\.)(?![\d\.])'. Other puncts are being treated by other regexes

Answer (score 0):

This might be overkill, or need a bit of cleanup, but here is the best regex I could come up with:

```
((([^\.\n ]+|(\.+\d+))\b[^\.]? ?)+)([\.?!\)\"]+)
```

To break it down:

```
[^\.\n ]+    // Matches 1+ times any char that isn't a dot, newline or space.
(\.+\d+)     // Captures the special case of decimal numbers
\b[^\.]? ?   // \b is a word boundary. This may be optionally  
             // followed by any non-dot character, and optionally a space.
```

All these previous parts are matches 1+ times. In order to determine that a sentence is finished, we use the following:

```
[\.?!\)\"] // Matches any of the common sentences terminators 1+ times
```

[Try it out!](https://regex101.com/r/ak3XYj/2)